# Pdo Pick a random row

Tags: php, pdo

Im trying to pick a random row from the database using pdo ive not found a way todo it with out using a while loop

```
$map = '1';
    
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM map_pokemon WHERE map = ? LIMIT 20');
$stmt->execute(array($map));

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       
        
        $rand_keys = array_rand($row['pokemon']);
        
    }
}
```

the pdo while loop grabs all results  i can print them off but now im trying to pick a random result  but getting this error
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_rand(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, string given in

i want to use the random result outside the while loop

i was using this

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT pokemon
 FROM map_pokemon WHERE map = ?
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$array = array('30');
$query->execute($array);

$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$wildPokemon = $result  ;
```

but i have moved to a vps now getting empty array

Comment: What if you removed the while. Did a fetch all and feed that to array_rand. I'm curious why your original solution stopped working.